# Where can I find data on the number of social media users who checked in to a store at any given period of time?

Tags: data-request

I want to build an application that helps the user figure out when, during a 24-hour period, to go to a store based on how busy that store will be. Ideally, the data will go as far back as possible (to account for seasonal trends).